# Skype Metro for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, skype

In Skype Metro, how can you change the setting to run the app as Administrator? I'm using Windows 8. I thought you only had to right click the tile.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is what you need to do to accomplish this:
>
> 1. Hit the Windows button on the keyboard + R This will bring up the run command
> 2. Type in regedit and hit enter.
> 3. Search for FilterAdministratorToken.
> 4. Change the value from 0 to 1
> 5. Log off and back in.   This will enable most Metro Apps. Some apps will still need a Microsoft Live log in.

Solution found [here](http://lazynetworkadmin.com/knowledgebase-mainmenu-6/2-windows/176-windows-8-administrator-cannot-run-metro-apps).

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the Windows Store Apps ("Metro") with admin rights. When you disable UAC you get a waring that UAC is required.